# Java Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Can't link program

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I try to link a basic shader program with a vertex and fragment shader.
Both shaders compile successfully, but if I try to link the program the linking always fails.
Whats wrong, why the linking is failing?
The info log is empty, but I get GL_INVALID_OPERATION error, when linking.
I run the MAIN code in the "onSurfaceCreated" method from the GLSurfaceView.Renderer interface.

MAIN:

```
String vertexShaderSource = "attribute vec4 a_Position;     " +
                            "void main()                    " +
                            "{                              " +
                            "   gl_Position = a_Position;   " +
                            "}                              ";

String fragmentShaderSource =   "precision mediump float;                   " +
                                "void main()                                " +
                                "{                                          " +
                                "   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);" +
                                "}                                          ";

int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShaderSource);
ShaderHelper.compileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShaderSource);
ShaderHelper.compileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);
ProgramHelper.linkProgram(fragmentShaderHandle);
```

HELPER:

```
public static void compileShader(int shaderHandle)
    {
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shaderHandle);
        int[] results = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, results, 0);

        if(results[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE)
        {
            String infoLog = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to compile shader!" + '\n' + infoLog);
        }
    }

    public static void linkProgram(int programHandle)
    {
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);
        int[] results = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, results, 0);

        if(results[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE)
        {
            String infoLog = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle);
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to link program!" + '\n' + infoLog);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

WTF, the program links fine, if I don't use the helper method to link.
Why???

Comment: All the written code looks ok, but can you post the exact error (what you get from the infolog? (I assume your program crashes in the helper function with the throwing of your runtimeException)

Comment: The info log is empty but I get GL_INVALID_OPERATION error.

Comment: did you correctly set the version of opengl? To use openGL ES 2.0 you have to call `setEGLContextClientVersion(2);` on the GLSurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

Your code passes the wrong argument to the `linkProgram()` method:

```
programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
...
ProgramHelper.linkProgram(fragmentShaderHandle);
```

As the name suggests, `fragmentShaderHandle` is the fragment shader object. For linking the program, you need to pass the program object:

```
ProgramHelper.linkProgram(programHandle);
```